# WebRequest/POST question on extracting specific data from a website

Tags: post, httpwebrequest

I am trying to gather data on specific events from a company website: http://pipeline.kindermorgan.com/infoposting/notices.aspx?type=CRIT
I have worked a lot of similar websites but so far they have been pretty simple and it’s just a matter of going to the website and working with the response stream. In this case the website requires you to select a value from the first combo box (TSP/TSP Name). Without any info being passed, the URL will return the data associated with the first item in the list. I really need to be able to get the data associated with any of the items in the list.

Here is the code I have been using thus far but it fails with a Server Error 500 so I am guessing that either I did not form the POST properly or am missing some data in the post data):

For the page I have listed above I just want to get a response stream with the table of the notices for a particular TSP from the combo box (starting with Trailblazer). I know the control is “ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlpipeline” and the value I want to send is 24. When I navigate via IE, I also have to press the “Retrieve” button.

When I look at the POST request using FireBug, I notice that there are a lot of other target/values included. I’m not sure if I need to send all of those as well and (having never done a POST before) I am not sure how to format the data in the POST to do that.

Bear with me if this request seems odd. I am more of a database person and am looking to automate a lot of the stuff we are required to look at manually every day. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
    var encoding = new ASCIIEncoding(); 

    var postData = "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlpipeline=24";

    byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

    string RemoteURI = "http://pipeline.kindermorgan.com/infoposting/notices.aspx?type=CRIT";

    var myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(RemoteURI);

    myRequest.Method = "POST";

    myRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    myRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;

    var newStream = myRequest.GetRequestStream();

    newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

    newStream.Close();

    var response = myRequest.GetResponse();

    var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();

    var responseReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
```

Comment: I havent looked at this in detail - but at a high level, if the browser is successfully posting data and getting back the response you need, then you should also send the same request in code. That will increase your chances of success.

Comment: Thanks feroze. I ended up making absolutely sure that the POST data I was building in the code was exactly the same as what I see when using FireBug and it still didn't work. Then in a moment of divine intervention, I remembered a previous effort which required the user agent to be set for the request. I did that and voila, it worked like a champ. Here is the code I added (for the benefit of others):
myRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)" ;

Answer (score 0):

I actually resolved the issue and there were a number of things I found out in the process that I will share for the benefit of others who may look at this thread.

First, I had to build the POST data exactly as it appears in the POST in a browser (I used Firebug to see the POST data). This meant getting the hidden arguments as well (particularly VIEWSTATE and EVENTVALIDATION). I was able to get these by just downloading the default page source for the page (by the way, i do this in the code because it is not static for this site) and parsing out the values for the hidden fields. I then build the POST data string with any changes I may have (in my case changing the date was important but in the future I may change other things).

Now the thing that really had me stumped. I confirmed that the POST data string was exactly the same as the one sent by FireFox/FireBug through a character by character comparison and it still wouldn't work. I then remembered in a previous scraping case that I had to set the user agent.

So here is the code I ended up with:

```
string postData = String.Format("__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__LASTFOCUS="
    + "&__VIEWSTATE={0}"
    + "&ctl00%24UltraWebTree1={1}"
    + "&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24ddlNoticeCategory={2}"
    + "&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24ddlpipeline={3}"
    + "&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24Button1={4}"
    + "&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24tbDate={5}"
    + "&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24ddlNoticeType={6}"
    + "&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24tbSubject={7}"
    + "&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24ddlNoticeSubType={8}"
    + "&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24ddlOrderBy={9}"
    + "&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24hfmode={10}"
    + "&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24hfODSCommand={11}&ctl00%24hfPipeline={12}"
    + "&__PREVIOUSPAGE={13}&__EVENTVALIDATION={14}",
    viewstate, webtree, noticecategory, pplcode, 
    button1, todaydate, noticetype, subject, 
    noticesubtype, orderby, hfmode, hfODSCommand, 
    hfPipeline, previouspage, eventvalidation);

var encoding = new ASCIIEncoding(); 
byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

var myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(RemoteURI); 
myRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)" ;
myRequest.Method = "POST" ;
myRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
myRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;

var newStream = myRequest.GetRequestStream(); 
newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
newStream.Close();

var myresponse = myRequest.GetResponse(); 
var responseStream = myresponse.GetResponseStream(); 
var responseReader = new StreamReader(responseStream); 
string webpagesource = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
```

Hope this helps someone else.